# byte.SequenceEqual returns corrent result when Dictionary.ContainsKey() does not

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two dictionaries dictionary<byte[], MyClass>. My keys (byte[]) are not generated by me and are guaranteed to be unique and immutable. When I use dictionary.ContainsKey() no match is found even though I know there is one. Why would ContainsKey not work on a byte array? I have not overriden any equality operators for byte arrays.

I have written an extension function for byte arrays to output the byte array to human readable text for convenience but the keys are actually stored as byte arrays:

```
    public static string ToHRString(this byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (!byteArray.Any()) return "No data in array";
        StringBuilder sb = new($"{byteArray[0]}");
        for (var index = 1; index < byteArray.Length; index++)
        {
            var b = byteArray[index];
            sb.Append($".{b}");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Here is an array I am searching for. This is the first key in the needle dictionary:

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.11.0.115.103.65.114.99.72.97.110.100.108.101.0.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

The all the keys of the haystack dictionary:

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.11.0.115.103.65.114.99.72.97.110.100.108.101.0.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.11.0.115.103.65.114.99.72.97.110.100.108.101.1.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.11.0.115.103.65.114.99.72.97.110.100.108.101.2.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.12.0.115.103.76.105.110.101.72.97.110.100.108.101.0.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.12.0.115.103.76.105.110.101.72.97.110.100.108.101.1.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

> 176.54.0.0.6.0.0.0.255.254.255.0.0.0.0.0.26.0.0.0.255.255.1.0.12.0.115.103.76.105.110.101.72.97.110.100.108.101.2.0.255.255.255.255.0.0.0.0

newValues is a dictionary who's key is the needle I am searching for.
_entityData is the haystack I am searching in.

```
foreach (var val in newValues)
{
    foreach (var entData in _entityData)
    {
        //Finds a match
        if (val.Key.SequenceEqual(entData.Key))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Match:");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NO MATCH:");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine($"{val.Key.ToHRString()}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"{entData.Key.ToHRString()}");
    }

    //Does NOT find a match
    if (_entityData.ContainsKey(val.Key))
    {
        var oldVal = _entityData.Where(a => a.Key.SequenceEqual(val.Key)).First();
        val.Value.Volume = oldVal.Value.Volume;
    }
}
```

Why wouldn't ContainsKey not work when key.SequenceEqual work?

Comment: arrays do not make for good keys because by default the comparison will be based on reference and not on the values within the array.  You can pass a custom `IEqualityComparer` to your dictionary that will compare the arrays the way you want and create hashes based on the values inside of them instead.

Comment: The key is a REFERENCE to the byte array, it will only compare equal if it's the same object.

Comment: If you instantiate dictionary it uses `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to compare keys. Default comparer for arrays checks only references, not values. You need to create your own `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` and pass it to dictionary's constructor

Comment: I suppose that methods like  _entityData.Remove(value.Key) will not work as well? What the comments point out makes sense. My problem now is I am receiving dictionaries that use the default EqualityComparer. I looked for a way to force my own EqualityComparer to be used but don't see that yet. I will need to do many operations based on if the values of the key are equal and not if the reference is equal.

Comment: I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633600/is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-non-default-equalitycomparer-to-a-dictionary-after-cr).